# Raspberry Pi Camera auto capture python script

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to set up my raspberry pi to auto take pictures every 5 seconds and save the file as image1,image2 etc. This is the Python code I have been trying:

```
import time
import picamera
counter = 0
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    for each in range(5):
        counter = counter + 1
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(5)
        camera.capture("/home/pi/python/Pictures/image",counter,".jpg")
        camera.stop_preview()
```

But every time I run this I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python/camera_repeated.py", line 9, in <module>
    camera.capture("/home/pi/python/Pictures/image",counter,".jpg")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1303, in capture
    format = self._get_image_format(output, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 684, in _get_image_format
    format[6:] if format.startswith('image/') else
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the string concatenation wrong. Strings in python should be concatenated with `+` between them. You're using the `,` sign, that normally separates arguments in function calls.

The signature for [`PiCamera.capture`](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.7/api.html?highlight=capture#picamera.PiCamera.capture) is defined as

```
capture(output, format=None, use_video_port=False, resize=None, splitter_port=0, **options)
```

So you will at first specify the output file as a string and then (optional) the format. If not specified a format, the format will be derived from the file extension of the given output file, so you can leave it empty here.

So the right call in line 9 should be:

```
camera.capture("/home/pi/python/Pictures/image" + str(counter) + ".jpg")
```

You're only giving in a string now. Before you gave in 3 params, with the format being the value of your `counter` variable and the third (`use_video_port`) with `.jpg`. Internally, the library seems to test the given format for common known mime-types `startswith('image/')`, but as you are giving in an integer, there is no such method `startswith`. That resulted in the error.

Comment: This looks like it should work and I have tested it but it now says: TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: I assume when I fix that it should function correctly?

Comment: Whoops, missed the conversion from int to string. You will need to use `str(counter)` to convert the int to string in order to do the string concatenation. Updated my answer, so now it should really work.

Answer (score 0):

i assumed below code is shorter and better:

for each in range (5):
camera.capture("/home/pi/python/Pictures/image%s.jpg" %each)
sleep (5)